# Working with MySQL and Xcode

Tags: mysql, xcode

I've been programing for some time now, and the thing I get asked the most is, how about  MySQL database.

What are some good sites for learning about data base programing  with xcode, so I can make a app work together with a web site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To integrate an iPhone/iPad application with mysql you need to develop webservices and then call them in your app. I would suggest the use of JSON, SOAP, XML or PHP, some examples:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2941/how-to-write-a-simple-phpmysql-web-service-for-an-ios-app
http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/11/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-intro-to-soap-web-services/
http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/43209

There are a lot of combinations possible.... you can use php or .net or other frameworks, so it's hard to give you a complete list of tutorials.

If you want to develop a regular iOS application, i would suggest this link:

http://blog.iosplace.com/?p=30

Hope it helps.

Comment: i want to log in to my mysql database and retrive the data and put it in a tableView in my app.